NSCFRunLoopSemaphore wait assertion error in NSInternalInconsistencyException
I've tried several ways to attempt to get async working in Playground. I've seen in a place where Task {} in combination with PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution() may be the way to go:
updated note: The PlaygroundPage code without the Task {} will result in an execution fail. The Task {} without the PlaygroundPage code will work, but the Playground will not stop running.
Task
{
  :
  :
  PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
}
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true



But I've tried that and it works enough to produce an output but crashes immediately after. It crashes with:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'assertion failed: '-[NSCFRunLoopSemaphore wait:] has been invoked on a thread which is incompatible with AppKit; the problem is likely in a much shallower frame in the backtrace' in -[NSCFRunLoopSemaphore wait:] on line 279 of file
When I look this up it seems the examples of why this happens is related to UI which this is not.

Full stacktrace below. Can someone help me understand why this goes wrong and what I need to do to fix it? The same general code in Project will work.
This is the example code I have:
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport

var inputs: [(Int, Int)] = [(Int, Int)]()

//random assignment
for _ in 0 ..< 1000
{
    inputs.append((Int.random(in: 1..<10), Int.random(in: 1..<10)))
}

func calculate_async(x: Int, y: Int) async -> Double
{
    //hypthothetical calculations
    let hypo: Double = sqrt(Double(x*x + y*y))
    let volt: Double = Double(x*y)
    return hypo * volt
}

func get_calculations_async(my inputs: [(Int, Int)]) async -> [Double]
{
    let processed_async = await withTaskGroup(of: Double.self, returning: [Double].self) { taskgroup_async in
        for input in inputs
        {
            taskgroup_async.addTask(priority: .background)
            {
                await calculate_async(x: input.0, y: input.1)
            }
        }
        var solutions_asnyc: [Double] = [Double]()
        for await results_async in taskgroup_async
        {
            solutions_asnyc.append(results_async)
        }
        return solutions_asnyc
    }
    return processed_async
}

Task
{
    var calculated_async: [Double] = []
    let clock_async = ContinuousClock()
    let time_async = await clock_async.measure
    {
        await calculated_async = get_calculations_async(my: inputs)
    }
    let t_async = Double(time_async.components.attoseconds) * 1e-15
    print("t async msecs: \(t_async)ms")
    PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
}
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

And this is the output
t async msecs: 315.011208ms
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'assertion failed: '-[NSCFRunLoopSemaphore wait:] has been invoked on a thread which is incompatible with AppKit; the problem is likely in a much shallower frame in the backtrace' in -[NSCFRunLoopSemaphore wait:] on line 279 of file /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/91a344b1-f985-11ee-b563-fe8bc7981bff/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ViewBridge/NSCFRunLoopSemaphore.m'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018ef372ec __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018ea1e788 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018ef5c268 _CFBundleGetValueForInfoKey + 0
    3   ViewBridge                          0x0000000197606788 -[NSCFRunLoopSemaphore wait:] + 304
    4   ViewBridge                          0x0000000197606578 -[NSCFRunLoopSemaphore wait] + 36
    5   com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-m 0x0000000102c26318 -[PlaygroundViewBridgeService finishExecutionNotification:] + 180
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018eeb7144 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 148
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018ef4b3d8 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 88
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018ef4b320 _CFXRegistrationPost + 440
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018ee85678 _CFXNotificationPost + 768
    10  Foundation                          0x000000018ffa24e4 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 88
    11  PlaygroundSupport                   0x000000010765e394 $s17PlaygroundSupport0A4PageC15finishExecutions5NeverOyF + 172
    12  ???                                 0x0000000107630dd4 0x0 + 4418899412
    13  ???                                 0x0000000107632b91 0x0 + 4418907025
    14  ???                                 0x0000000107632ec9 0x0 + 4418907849
    15  libswift_Concurrency.dylib          0x0000000256f570f9 _ZL23completeTaskWithClosurePN5swift12AsyncContextEPNS_10SwiftErrorE + 1
)


You need to set PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true before you start any asynchronous work.
You don't need the unstructured Task either. await is fine in the root of playground  code
Update The Task is needed in macOS playgrounds but not iPadOS playgrounds.
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

var inputs: [(Int, Int)] = [(Int, Int)]()

//random assignment
for _ in 0 ..< 1000
{
    inputs.append((Int.random(in: 1..<10), Int.random(in: 1..<10)))
}

func calculate_async(x: Int, y: Int) async -> Double
{
    //hypthothetical calculations
    let hypo: Double = sqrt(Double(x*x + y*y))
    let volt: Double = Double(x*y)
    return hypo * volt
}

func get_calculations_async(my inputs: [(Int, Int)]) async -> [Double]
{
    let processed_async = await withTaskGroup(of: Double.self, returning: [Double].self) { taskgroup_async in
        for input in inputs
        {
            taskgroup_async.addTask(priority: .background)
            {
                await calculate_async(x: input.0, y: input.1)
            }
        }
        var solutions_asnyc: [Double] = [Double]()
        for await results_async in taskgroup_async
        {
            solutions_asnyc.append(results_async)
        }
        return solutions_asnyc
    }
    return processed_async
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

Task {
    var calculated_async: [Double] = []
    let clock_async = ContinuousClock()
    let time_async = await clock_async.measure
    {
        await calculated_async = get_calculations_async(my: inputs)
    }
    let t_async = Double(time_async.components.attoseconds) * 1e-15
    print("t async msecs: \(t_async)ms")

    PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
} 



This code as written does not work. It produces this error instead:
Playground execution failed:
error: execution stopped with unexpected state.
error: Execution was interrupted.
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

The updated code won't work as written. The PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution() needs to go inside the Task because the Task thread will run asynchronously and finish after the main Playground thread. This is why you can put PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true at the bottom of the code after the Task since the Task thread will still be running. As written, the Playground will exit as soon as it starts once it reaches the finishExecution() before the Task can really kick-off its own thread so nothing in Task ever gets executed.

No. The needsIndefiniteExecutio is in the right place. I just didn't move the finishExecution

Hi @Paulw11, I do really appreciate your help on this, but unfortunately the code as written will return the same CoreFoundation crash I originally posted with.

It works for me.  output is t async msecs: 714.6048330000001ms.  Playgrounds 4.5.1  macOS 14.4.1

maybe it's a bug or something with the current version then.. Swift Playground 5.10 macOS Sonoma 14.5  :(

Playgrounds 4.5.1 is the current macOS release.
